# In Datomic, how to add new entities (as references) to the many attribute of an existing entity

Tags: clojure, datomic

By way of example I'm going to use a drawing as the existing entity which is to have two new shapes added to it. This is the tx that is failing:

```clj
[{:shape/id "BKF806TXXTAFWII0", :db/id "22NF08ZVGH9N7QGG_0"}
 {:shape/id "YKIZU4CJC0JXJKVQ", :db/id "22NF08ZVGH9N7QGG_1"}
 [:db/add 17592186047451 :drawing/shapes ["22NF08ZVGH9N7QGG_0" "22NF08ZVGH9N7QGG_1"]]]
```

As you can see the existing drawing has `:db/id` of 17592186047451. I'm trying to create two new shapes and add them to the cardinality many attribute `:drawing/shapes`. "22NF08ZVGH9N7QGG_0" and "22NF08ZVGH9N7QGG_1" are tempids that are supposed to be translated to the same new `:db/id`s wherever they appear.

I should say that the drawing doesn't have any existing shapes. If it did I would expect them to be orphaned.

This is the error message I'm getting:

**Execution error (ExceptionInfo) at datomic.client.api.async/ares (async.clj:58).
Cannot interpret as a keyword: 22NF08ZVGH9N7QGG_0, no leading :**

Something similar I've also tried:

```clj
[{:shape/id "9HTL5BMMHT6QUJM6", :db/id "22NF08ZVGH9N7QGG_0"}
 {:shape/id "O5UB9IG9UB8KDVA2", :db/id "22NF08ZVGH9N7QGG_1"}
 [:db/add 17592186047451 :drawing/shapes "22NF08ZVGH9N7QGG_0"]
 [:db/add 17592186047451 :drawing/shapes "22NF08ZVGH9N7QGG_1"]]
```

Gives this error message:

**Execution error (ExceptionInfo) at datomic.client.api.async/ares (async.clj:58).
Two datoms in the same transaction conflict
{:d1
[17592186047451 :drawing/shapes 17592186049126 13194139538021 true],
:d2
[17592186047451 :drawing/shapes 17592186049127 13194139538021 true]}**

This gives the same error message as the first attempt:

```clj
[{:db/id 17592186047451, :drawing/shapes ["22NF08ZVGH9N7QGG_0" "22NF08ZVGH9N7QGG_1"]}
 {:shape/id "3DZYWHEPQIAELF25", :db/id "22NF08ZVGH9N7QGG_0"}
 {:shape/id "GJ804SOOU36YQX6Y", :db/id "22NF08ZVGH9N7QGG_1"}]
```

Getting rid of the tempids by doing it in a nested way:

```clj
[{:db/id 17592186047451,
  :drawing/shapes
  [{:shape/id "GEMRMRFG0E6N262M"}
   {:shape/id "HTH2C7R90BQFFNXT"}]}]
```

Just yields this error message:

**Execution error (ExceptionInfo) at datomic.client.api.async/ares (async.clj:58).
Unable to resolve entity: {:shape/id "GEMRMRFG0E6N262M"}**

Comment: The first error message has seen that it is a vector so is looking for an ident (i.e. first position is a keyword). `:db/add` only works for one at a time, so will never be interpreting a  vector as 'many'.

Comment: In retrospect the second error message should have been a hint that `:drawing/shapes` only takes one. That message doesn't occur when the cardinality is properly defined as many. Adding another when there should only be one is a 'conflict'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example

```
[{:shape/id "9HTL5BMMHT6QUJM6", :db/id "22NF08ZVGH9N7QGG_0"}
 {:shape/id "O5UB9IG9UB8KDVA2", :db/id "22NF08ZVGH9N7QGG_1"}
 [:db/add 17592186047451 :drawing/shapes "22NF08ZVGH9N7QGG_0"]
 [:db/add 17592186047451 :drawing/shapes "22NF08ZVGH9N7QGG_1"]]
```

and third example

```
[{:db/id 17592186047451, :drawing/shapes ["22NF08ZVGH9N7QGG_0" "22NF08ZVGH9N7QGG_1"]}
 {:shape/id "3DZYWHEPQIAELF25", :db/id "22NF08ZVGH9N7QGG_0"}
 {:shape/id "GJ804SOOU36YQX6Y", :db/id "22NF08ZVGH9N7QGG_1"}]
```

should work. Perhaps your `:drawing/shapes` attribute is not `:db.cardinality/many`?

Comment: I thought it was cardinality many but ran the schema creation again (just for that attribute) and indeed the second example worked fine.